# JQuery 3.1 failing to grab DOM when used inside chrome content scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am new to developing chrome extensions, though I understand the concept of content scripts and isolated worlds. I just can't grasp the actual issue.

I am aware there is a lot of posts in StackOverflow for Jquery not working in Content Scripts ( Chrome Extension ). Most do not seem to address why.

My Code as follows

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "TestExtension",
  "description": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "MyExtension"
  },
  "content_scripts":[{
    "js":["js/lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js","js/app/content.js"],
    "matches":["<all_urls>","http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "run_at":"document_start"
  }],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src https://*.google.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "minimum_chrome_version":"22",
  "web_accessible_resources" : [
    "js/lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "contextMenus",
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "identity",
    "*://*.google.com/*"
  ],
}
```

I am trying to grab some DOM content from gmail.

- I have used content script matches pattern to all urls for test purposes.
- And so is Content Security Policy (unsafe-eval) and Web_Accessible_Resources ( Trial and error stuff )
- I have provided almost all the permissions to check whats causing the issue.

**Content.js**

```
console.log('I am Content Script');

var jq = $.noConflict();

if (typeof jq == 'undefined') {
    console.log('JQuery Not Loaded');   
}else{
    console.log('JQuery Loaded');   
}

jq(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("editable"));
    console.log(jq("body").className);
});
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

1. The Content Script gets injected to the Page.
2. The Jquery is loaded. And I have used noConflict() to make sure i am not running into any internal script conflicts.
3. The Vanilla JS grabs the DOM element.
4. But the Jquery fails not grab anything. No error messages shown.

**Question:**

I am aware of the **"chrome.runtime.sendMessage"**  and **"chrome.runtime.onMessage"** and its neccessity during messaging. But do i have to wrap the logic inside this onMessage ?

Also, I have seen some solutions using the script injection ( **chrome.tabs.executeScript** ) , But is it the only solution. I feel like i am missing something in manifest.json could someone point out if i have missed something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried changing run_at to document end, document start and document idle but nothing works.

Comment: The page constructs itself dynamically so the elements appears long time past document_end was fired. You can use the hidden gmail API in `gmonkey` object or listen to `message` event on `window`: the site will emit something like `s.ready` inside. Or use the universal method: MutationObserver, see also [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: And before you ask: `HTMLCollection[0]` in the console means that at the time the object was printed it had 0 elements, but when you expanded it the *live* HTMLCollection got populated with the now existing elements.

Comment: $("body")[0].className, jquery always return a collection of matching elements

Comment: @wOxxOm : Thank you for the insight, so $(document).ready() would not work ? I thought it would wait until the DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: jQuery `ready` waits for DOMContentLoaded event fired by the browser, so it's totally useless, because it's the same as document_end or document_idle which is the default mode of injection for content scripts. I mean the site starts to update the page *after* that moment.

Comment: Also, how do you expect `ready` to know when the dynamic update has finished? It's absolutely impossible because the site may continue to update itself with JavaScript + ajax without ever stopping. Which is why I've linked that topic.

Comment: Ah, I see, now it makes sense, so I would have to listen for an event after the ajax update is done.

Comment: Yeah, using .ajaxComplete() listener might also be a solution, I haven't tried it on gmail though unlike the methods I mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm, Thanks for the suggestion, Will try it out and post it here if its works :) Cheers

Comment: Please, consider weather you need jQuery. jQuery is 85kiB of minimized code. That is a significant burden to require for your extension. jQuery is quite useful in many circumstances, but not for what's in the question. While it's possible you really *need* to load jQuery, it is more likely that you are doing so for the convenience of saving a couple/few hundred characters in your own code by not using vanilla JavaScript (as is the case in the question's code). If that is the case in your project (we have no way to know), doing so is a poor trade-off from your user's point of view.

Comment: Good Point ! in my case i require tooltipster and highlight plugin to work. Hence i am caught in the dependency cycle.